# PJSUA2 sip android native app

Tags: android, android-ndk, sip, voip, pjsip

Here I'm developing an application using native android in ubuntu 14.04LTS eclipse adt for android.

Build, configure, and make everything went perfect.

After that I imported pjsua2 sample app into eclipse, I then added native library support but when I run on emulator it throws an error.

The error log,

> 10-25 06:12:09.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1571): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   10-25 06:12:09.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1571): Process:
>   org.pjsip.pjsua2.app, PID: 1571 10-25 06:12:09.489:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1571): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load
>   libpjsua2.so from loader
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app-2,
>   /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null 10-25
>   06:12:09.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1571): at
>   java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:358) 10-25 06:12:09.489:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1571): at
>   java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:526) 10-25 06:12:09.489:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1571): at org.pjsip.pjsua2.app.MyApp.(MyApp.java:235)
>   10-25 06:12:09.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1571): at
>   org.pjsip.pjsua2.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:85) 10-25
>   06:12:09.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1571): at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 10-25
>   06:12:09.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1571): at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
>   10-25 06:12:09.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1571): at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
>   10-25 06:12:09.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1571): at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
>   10-25 06:12:09.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1571): at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 10-25
>   06:12:09.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1571): at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
>   10-25 06:12:09.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1571): at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 10-25
>   06:12:09.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1571): at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 10-25 06:12:09.489:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1571): at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017) 10-25
>   06:12:09.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1571): at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 10-25
>   06:12:09.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1571): at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 10-25 06:12:09.489:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1571): at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
>   10-25 06:12:09.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1571): at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595) 10-25
>   06:12:09.489: E/AndroidRuntime(1571): at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 10-25 06:12:09.499:
>   W/ActivityManager(403): Force finishing activity
>   org.pjsip.pjsua2.app/.MainActivity 10-25 06:12:09.809:
>   I/WindowManager(403): Screenshot max retries 4 of Token{b4148710
>   ActivityRecord{b41c4ef8 u0 org.pjsip.pjsua2.app/.MainActivity t2 f}}
>   appWin=Window{b4086b40 u0 Starting org.pjsip.pjsua2.app} drawState=4
>   10-25 06:12:09.809: W/WindowManager(403): Screenshot failure taking
>   screenshot for (480x800) to layer 21010 10-25 06:12:10.009:
>   D/dalvikvm(403): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 91K, 14% free 7331K/8436K, paused
>   72ms, total 74ms 10-25 06:12:10.359: W/ActivityManager(403): Activity
>   pause timeout for ActivityRecord{b41c4ef8 u0
>   org.pjsip.pjsua2.app/.MainActivity t2 f} 10-25 06:12:10.719:
>   I/Choreographer(403): Skipped 94 frames! The application may be doing
>   too much work on its main thread. 10-25 06:12:10.869:
>   I/Choreographer(581): Skipped 35 frames! The application may be doing
>   too much work on its main thread. 10-25 06:12:11.599: I/Process(1571):
>   Sending signal. PID: 1571 SIG: 9 10-25 06:12:11.609: E/SoundPool(403):
>   error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg 10-25
>   06:12:11.609: W/AudioService(403): Soundpool could not load file:
>   /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg 10-25 06:12:11.659:
>   I/ActivityManager(403): Process org.pjsip.pjsua2.app (pid 1571) has
>   died. 10-25 06:12:11.669: E/SoundPool(403): error loading
>   /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg 10-25 06:12:11.669:
>   W/AudioService(403): Soundpool could not load file:
>   /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg 10-25 06:12:11.669:
>   E/SoundPool(403): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
>   10-25 06:12:11.669: W/AudioService(403): Soundpool could not load
>   file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg 10-25 06:12:11.669:
>   E/SoundPool(403): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
>   10-25 06:12:11.669: W/AudioService(403): Soundpool could not load
>   file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg 10-25 06:12:11.669:
>   E/SoundPool(403): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
>   10-25 06:12:11.669: W/AudioService(403): Soundpool could not load
>   file: /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg 10-25 06:12:11.669:
>   E/SoundPool(403): error loading
>   /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg 10-25 06:12:11.669:
>   W/AudioService(403): Soundpool could not load file:
>   /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg 10-25 06:12:11.669:
>   E/SoundPool(403): error loading
>   /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg 10-25 06:12:11.669:
>   W/AudioService(403): Soundpool could not load file:
>   /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg 10-25 06:12:11.669:
>   E/SoundPool(403): error loading
>   /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg 10-25 06:12:11.669:
>   W/AudioService(403): Soundpool could not load file:
>   /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg 10-25 06:12:11.669:
>   E/SoundPool(403): error loading
>   /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg 10-25 06:12:11.669:
>   W/AudioService(403): Soundpool could not load file:
>   /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg 10-25 06:12:11.669:
>   E/SoundPool(403): error loading
>   /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg 10-25 06:12:11.669:
>   W/AudioService(403): Soundpool could not load file:
>   /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg 10-25 06:12:11.669:
>   W/AudioService(403): onLoadSoundEffects(), Error -1 while loading
>   samples 10-25 06:12:12.259: I/Choreographer(403): Skipped 171 frames!
>   The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. 10-25
>   06:12:12.609: W/InputMethodManagerService(403): Window already
>   focused, ignoring focus gain of:
>   com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@b410f460
>   attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@b405a130

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed this https://github.com/VoiSmart/pjsip-android-builder link to build the pjsip hope it would help others but still facing some problems in video calling related.

Answer (score 1):

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load libpjsua2.so from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app-2, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null
```

I had the same error.
The android sample app tries to load this **libpjsua2.so** from  the JNILIBs folder path but it couldnt find it so it throws the above error.Hope my answer helps someone .

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It seems you was building pjsip library using newest ndk. Try older version of ndk and rebuild pjsip.

Comment: Yes I'am using newest ndk10 version,ok i will try with older version ndk8. thanks for reply, if any problems comes i will contact you

Comment: Hi @YLS, which version of ndk works for you? I have the same problem