# UnsatisfiedLinkError in pjsip library

Tags: android, pjsip, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I build Pjsip library and use its sample in android studio .

**question**

When I run that i got this error.How could I solve it ? thanks in advance.

**exception**

> jsip.pjsua2.app E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                       Process: org.pjsip.pjsua2.app, PID: 4360
>                                                                       java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void org.pjsip.pjsua2.pjsua2JNI.swig_module_init() (tried Java_org_pjsip_pjsua2_pjsua2JNI_swig_1module_1init and Java_org_pjsip_pjsua2_pjsua2JNI_swig_1module_1init__)
>                                                                           at org.pjsip.pjsua2.pjsua2JNI.swig_module_init(Native Method)
>                                                                           at org.pjsip.pjsua2.pjsua2JNI.(pjsua2JNI.java:2351)
>                                                                           at org.pjsip.pjsua2.Endpoint.(Endpoint.java:68)
>                                                                           at org.pjsip.pjsua2.app.MyApp.(MyApp.java:296)
>                                                                           at org.pjsip.pjsua2.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:92)
>                                                                           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
>                                                                           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
>                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2332)
>                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2442)
>                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
>                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1351)
>                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
>                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5389)
>                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1020)
>                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:815)

Comment: have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26561508/pjsua2-sip-android-native-app ?

Comment: thanks for your response ,but  Error is different in your link .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It may happen for several reasons. First, check if you attached the native library correctly. For that create a folder named "jniLibs" into the projects

> app/src/main/jniLibs

then put your armeabi architecture library like

> armeabi/libpjsua2.so

for other architecture like armeabi-v7a use

> armeabi-v7a/libpjsua2.so

like this.

there are other reasons may happen. If you build `pjsip` library for `armeabi` architecture only and running your application in an `x86` architecture device then this error may occur. So check it also if you have built it for that application.

Comment: Thanks for answer .and How could I check which version I use armeabi  ?

Comment: It is work  in Eclipse , but in Android Studio I got this exception

Comment: create the folder "jniLibs" and inside it create "armeabi" folder and paste ur library according to my answer.It will work.

Comment: Thank you sir . I created JniLibs but I didn't put that inside JniLibs ,  instead I put in Libs folder. But You helped ,it work perfectly .Thanks sir again.

Comment: Hi riaz-hasan and @hesenlieldar, I have the same problem, this is my [directory](http://es.tinypic.com?ref=n1xrfn), I don't get what the problem is

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this thread: [building pjsua2 dll](https://github.com/siniypin/pjsip4net/issues/15#issuecomment-299624711)

the important thing to know here is that the error you show in your question is caused by the fact that the pjsua2.dll (a c++ dll) is not in your output directory.